# Earth colonization by life from Mars

Tags: story-identification, mars

I am looking for the author of a book - or perhaps a trilogy - about an invasion from Mars.

This invasion involves Martian symbiotic life forms propagating to Earth and slowly changing the ecology of Earth to match their needs.

The humans attempt to fight those aggressive Martian worms, and also attempting to use nuclear bombs to fight off the Martian invasion.

I originally read it in a foreign language, but I think it is a modern English science-fiction opera, with an American author.

I want to go back and read it again. Search on-line did not help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Could you give us any more information, like when was the book published, or at least when you read it? Do you know if it was American, or British, or published elsewhere? An invasion from Mars is a theme that goes back at least to H.G. Wells in 1897, so any more plot details or characters would help.

Comment: I think it was a trilogy about marsian life form infested earth. There are a few big areas. People try to fight it up to use of nuclear bomb. Marsian life slowly changing earth into alien planet

Comment: It would be best if you could edit it into the question itself. It would be easiest for people to see and (hopefully) recognize.

Comment: I think it was a trilogy about marsian life form infested earth. There are a few big areas. People try to fight it up to use of nuclear bomb. Marsian life slowly changing earth into alien planet. I think it is a modern English science fiction opera. All I remember is a in detail description marsian simbiotic life propagating on earth. Human fighting aggressive worms. So I read it in foreign language. I think it was American author. English is my second language. I want to go back and read it again. Search on line did not help. Thanks a lot

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit to make it easier to notice the prominent details. I hope it helps. Feel free to roll back the changes if you feel it misses the point.

Comment: It may help to know what language you read it in as it may help rule out particular books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not specifically Martian (could you have misremembered the source of the aliens?) but David Gerrold's [The War Against the Chtorr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_Against_the_Chtorr) has an alien invasion which starts with changing the ecology of Earth (I also seem to remember worm like organisms taking part).

Comment: Yes Oh guys you are so good you are so right exactly it